# What is the origin of the term "punycode"?

Tags: punycode

I don't see any explanation of the name in [the RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3492), in [the Wikipedia article on punycode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punycode), or elsewhere in my google searches, but maybe I didn't look hard enough.

Why is it called "punycode"? What's "puny" about it?

Comment: The best I could find is because it is a PUN on "UNIcode" (Unicode) Uni rhymes with puny.

Comment: @Analog Where did you find that, if you don't mind sharing?

Comment: Here you go - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk%3APunycode#WHY_IS_IT_CALLED_PUNYCODE?

Comment: @Analog Very interesting, thanks for sharing. I just replied to the user who commented that on Wikipedia, asking if they have a source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I emailed Punycode RFC writer Adam M. Costello, and he replied by quoting an email of his from 2002:

> It is “puny” in three senses: The repertoire of characters used in the encoded strings is small, the encoded strings are short, and the implementation is small.

I have a longer write-up about it here:

https://www.maxlaumeister.com/articles/why-is-it-called-punycode/